# Linked-in Once Authenticated : while calling Url of user Profile again ask for authentication

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am Using `LinkedIn-j` API for LinkedIn Integration.
*I am able to post Status Update.*
I want *to Show User Profile in WebView* in Android for That I am getting User Public URL using below code.

```
person.getSiteStandardProfileRequest().getUrl();
```

which returning something like this `http://www.linkedin.com/profileviewProfile=&key=100652876&authToken=AWW7&authType=name&trk=api*a169149*s177398*`

If **I am going to open this url in WebView then its Redirecting to LinkedIn Login page and after filling Credential I can see user Profile**.

I want to open User Profile without entering Credential,**Again**

I also tried by appending the

```
URL&accesstoken="tokenIdReturned by Application";
```

But still I am not able to open the User Profile directly.
What I am missing?

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @thinksteep There is no error/no force close , just it makes mendatory to login again I want to keep the session/cookie alive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same Requirement and i have done it with doing two things.

**Firstly**  I have used My own WebView to load different URL to authenticate and to show profiles.I have made my `WebView` as `public static` *instead using the default browser I have redirect the calls to my own WebView in my Activity*.

**Second** I have set `webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);` so now it doesn't ask for login again while viewing the profile.

I have declared my Activity as `singleInstace` in Manifest.xml file.

UPDATE:

The way I used the WebView in My Activity.

```
public static WebView WV = null;
String uri;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    if (WV == null) {
        WV = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        WV.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WV.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); // the important change
        WV.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        WV.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF,
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String token = pref.getString(PREF_TOKEN, null);
    final String tokenSecret = pref.getString(PREF_TOKENSECRET, null);
    if (token == null || tokenSecret == null) {
        startAutheniticate();
    } else {
        showCurrentUser(new LinkedInAccessToken(token, tokenSecret));
    }

}


void startAutheniticate() {
    final LinkedInRequestToken liToken = oAuthService
            .getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
    uri = liToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
    getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET, liToken.getTokenSecret())
            .commit();
    WV.loadUrl(uri);
}

void showCurrentUser(final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken) {
    // code to get Profile object using Linkedin-J API 
    //which is already available on the API site as Example

    WV.loadUrl(profile.getSiteStandardProfileRequest().getUrl());
}
```